# Is something::something something() also a way to use scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I was trying to understand a C++ program which used point cloud library and in that code I came across a strange syntax -

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
```

I read about scope resolution operator but I am still confused whether or not this ''cloud_normals'' is a function of Ptr library. Can someone help me understand whats happening in this line of code?

Comment: It is a variable declaration and `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr` is the type.

Comment: `pcl` is probably a namespace `PointCloud` a template type in this namespace and `Ptr` a inner type or a type alias that is defined in this type. The definition of the type could look something like this: `namespace pcl { template<typename T> struct PointCloud { using Ptr = T*; };}`

Comment: @molbdnilo Why would a variable declaration have a () brackets after the variable? Is it because of the constructor?

Comment: That's one way to write an initializer. E.g. you could write `int x(42);`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Okay. I didn't know that, probably because it is not very common. Thanks

Comment: Obligatory [The Nightmare of Initialization in C++](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs) by Nicolai Josuttis.  An hour long presentation on the initialization syntax pain point in C++.  (Because all the variations of "not very common" are all too common.)

Comment: @Eljay   haha. It is really a pain.

Comment: No it is not.  The bit in the `()` after `cloud_normals` is `new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>`, which is an expression.   So the line is a definition of a variable named `cloud_normals` with type `pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr` that is initialised with the expression `new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>`.   If the bit in the `()` was not an expression (e.g. there is nothing, or it is a list of types) then then line would declare `cloud_normals` as a function (with arguments of those supplied types, and return value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>::Ptr cloud_normals(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::Normal>);
```

Here `cloud_normals` is a `shared pointer` to a `PointCloud` which contains `pcl::Normal` types. Check [here](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_point_cloud.html#ab805ba3b19e952ad19d084a9caa3dc60).

This line is creating an object of type `PointCloud<pcl::Normal>` and assigning it to the share pointer `cloud_normals`.